# Angular ng-view is not working

Tags: html, angularjs, routes, single-page-application

Here is my code for html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="movieModule">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1, width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular.resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../Scripts/movie-module.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/Category/category-controller.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/Category/category-repository.js"></script>

    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/themes/spacelab.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Movies Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand active" href="#">Brand</a>
                </div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="Movies.html">Movies</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Categories.html">Categories</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Artists.html">Artists</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
        <div class="row">
            <div ng-view=""></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my routing configation file:

```
var movieModule = angular.module("movieModule", ['ngRoute', 'ngResource'])
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/Categories.html', { templateUrl: '/Categories.html', controller: 'categoryController' });
});
```

I am trying to create a sample Single Page Application using angularjs. But my routing is not loading the ng-view when I click on `Categories` Menu.

Html for my Category Page is:

```
<div class="well">
    <div class="table-responsive" ng-controller="categoryController">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="category in categories">
                    <td>{{ category.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ category.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ category.description }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have an error in Web Console ? Is the path correct in your templateUrl ? It has to be relative to your main html file.

Comment: try `<div ng-view></div>` instead of `<div ng-view=""></div>`

Answer (score 1):

your links should be like this

```
<li><a href="#/Categories.html">Categories</a></li>
```

and

remove

```
   ng-controller="categoryController" in myCategory html
```

**OR**

remove

`controller: 'categoryController'` in `config of $routeProvider`

if u keep these two, the js controller wil execute for 2 times

Comment: No nothing is happening. Previously, It was redirecting to the Categories page but was not applying angular databinding on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full example

**HTML**
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="app">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.2.0" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.2.17" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.17/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand active" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="Movies.html">Movies</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#/Categories.html">Categories</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#/Artists.html">Artists</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <div class="row">
      <div ng-view=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Categories.html**

```
<div class="well">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="category in categories">
          <td>{{ category.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ category.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ category.description }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/Categories.html', {
      templateUrl: 'Categories.html',
      controller: 'CategoriesCtrl'
    })
      .when('/Artists.html', {
        templateUrl: 'Artists.html'
        //controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/index'
    });
  }
]);

app.controller("CategoriesCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.categories = [{
    id: '1',
    name: 'shohel',
    description: 'SSSSSSSSSSSSSSS'
  }, {
    id: '2',
    name: 'shohel',
    description: 'SSSSSSSSSSSSSSS'
  }];

});
```

**[plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/BZ2mdmx946qaUJEcEHxC?p=preview)**

Key point change

1. templateUrl: 'Categories.html'
2. `<li><a href="#/Categories.html">Categories</a>`
3. remove ng-controller="categoryController" in myCategory html